# How do i run nikto.pl file from wapiti.py file?

Tags: python, perl

I am working on a project which involves wapiti and nikto web tools. i have managed to produce one report for both these tool with this command

```
python wapiti.py www.kca.ac.ke ;perl nikto.pl -h www.kca.ac.ke -Display V -F htm -output /root/.wapiti/generated_report/index.html.
```

But i would like to run a command like

```
python wapiti.py www.kca.ac.ke
```

and get both the wapiti and nikto web scan report. How do i achieve this guys?

Comment: How about a simple shell script that runs both and then just trigger the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

A shell script would work.  Save the following as 'run_wapiti_and_nikto_scans', then run it as:

```
bash run_wapiti_and_nikto_scans www.my.site.com
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                 

SITE=$1
if [ -n "$SITE" ]; then  # -n tests to see if the argument is non empty                     
    echo "Looking to scan $SITE"
    echo "Running 'python wapiti.py $SITE'"
    python wapiti.py $SITE || echo "Failed to run wapiti!" && exit 1;

    echo "Running 'perl nikto.pl -h $SITE -Display V -F htm -output /root/.wapiti/generated_report/index.html'"
    perl nikto.pl -h $SITE -Display V -F htm -output /root/.wapiti/generated_report/index.html || echo "Failed to run nikto!" && exit 1;
    echo "Done!"
    exit 0; # Success                                                                      
fi

echo "usage: run_wapiti_and_nikto_scans www.my.site.com";
exit 1; # Failure
```